# Issue on Rendering List in Grid in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to render a simple `List` into a Grid like

```
var sr = new BindingSource();
sr.DataSource = str;
dataGridView1.DataSource = sr;
```

I am not getting any error but not able to display the list in Grid. Here is the entire code

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Enum
{
    public enum Sex {Male, Female, Other };
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Sex> str = new List<Sex>();
            str.Add(Sex.Female);
            str.Add(Sex.Male);

            var sr = new BindingSource();
            sr.DataSource = str;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = sr;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `dataGridView1.Refresh()` to force a redraw of the UI?

Comment: I Just added it to the code but nothing happen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataGridView` cannot bind to a list of primitive values (like `int`, `decimal`, `DateTime`, `enum`, `string` etc.) because it requires a list containing objects with **properties**.

The easiest way is to use LINQ projection to an anonymous type with single property like this (`BindingSource` is not needed at all):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Sex> str = new List<Sex>();
    str.Add(Sex.Female);
    str.Add(Sex.Male);

    dataGridView1.DataSource = str.Select(value => new { Sex = value }).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        public Sex Sex { get; set; }
    }

    public enum Sex { Male, Female, Other };

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingList<Person> persons = new BindingList<Person>();

        persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Joe", Lastname = "Doe" , Sex = Sex.Male});
        persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Nancy", Lastname = "Foo" , Sex = Sex.Female});

        dataGridView1.DataSource = persons;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind an enum to GridView. This is what I could get working

```
public class Person
{
    public Sex Gender { get; set; }
}
```

You need to use `BindingList` as list does not implement `IBindingList`

```
var list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Gender = Sex.Male, },
    new Person { Gender = Sex.Female, },
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```